# I want to create drop down box in input.phtml. (don't use zend_form)

Tags: zend-framework

I want to create drop down box in input.phtml.

I want to Create drop down box. select data from database.
and use get select data by function fetchAll() (joinLeft,where,order)

Case 1 : Don't use zend_form (Because i use table layout page input.phtml)

Case 2 : use zend_form

I want to answer two case and example
, The answer as to better ?

Thank for Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 :

In your view :

```
echo $this->formSelect('name', 'Option 1', array(), 
    array('Option 1', 'Option 2'));
```

1st arg : name of the select, 2nd arg : value; 3rd arg : attributs, 4th arg : options

Case 2 :

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form
{
    function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('select', 'my_select', 
            array('label' => 'My select', 
           'multioptions' => array('Option 1', 'Option 2'), value => 'Option 1'));
    }
}
```

In your controller :

```
$this->view->form = new MyForm();
```

In your view :

```
// Render the form opening tag
echo $this->form->renderForm(false);
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>'
// Render only the label
echo $this->form->my_select->renderLabel();
echo '</th>
echo '<td>';
// Render only the select
echo $this->form->my_select->renderViewHelper();
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
```

As you can see, Zend_Form is very flexible. So **USE IT**.

You can use Zend_Db::fetchPairs to fetch your options from the database.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh Thank. very good answer Case 2. I want to this case. It my problem for Zend Form. ha ha ha. Thank you very much

Comment: if i use renderViewHelper ($this->form->my_select->renderViewHelper();). Can i use validate in MyForm? Show example please.

Comment: Yes, render* methods are only for outputting html. Validation is handled when you're calling $form->isValid in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Well, do this

in you  view phtml file you can direcly call db table model

**UPDATE**

On your controller

```
$model = new Model_Somemodel();
$modelvalues = $model->fetchAll();

if(count($modelvalues) > 0)
    $this->view->modelvalues = $modelvalues
```

And on your view file

```
<select>
<?php  if($this->modelvalues): ?>
    <?php foreach($this->modelvalues as $value)
        echo "<option>".$value->somefiled."</option>";
     ?>     
<?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank for answer. but i want to query database in controllers side (controller.php) and send value to view side (.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

First case - You can use [formSelect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select) helper in your view.
Second case - use `Zend_Form_Element_Select` in your `Zend_Form`.

Comment: Thank for answer. I want to code example formSelect in case 1. can your help me.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recover the value of the val (2nd arg)

```
formSelect('name', '**Option 1**', array(), 
    array('Option 1', 'Option 2'));
```

1st arg: name of the select, 2nd arg: value; 3rd arg: attributs, 4th arg: options

in input.phtml.

Comment: Is that an additional question, or does this answer the question in any way? It's not clear to me.